# Azure AD Group Claim convert to lowercase using Regex

Tags: regex, azure-active-directory

I am trying to convert Group claim in azure to lowercase using regex replacement pattern.

This is my SAML response for the group claim.

> Attribute
> Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups">
> **AD-Saml-Group**

[image]

Currently, it is replacing the claim to :

> \L.*AD-.*\E

I want to convert AD-Saml-Group to ad-saml-group.

Thank you!

Comment: Please check this MsDocs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims

Comment: This is the first doc we referred to. It did not help. We are not able to convert the group claim to all lowercase. At this point, I am not sure if it can happen or not(no supporting link for that).

Answer (score 0):

Researched on this requirement, below are the findings.
The UI doesn't support making the output lowercase. It can be done with msgraph/powershell but you won't be able to use the UI to make changes to this claim in the future.

From the UI the only transformation available for groups is regex. If you want to do regex + lowercase you have to do it from MSGraph / powershell using claims mapping policy. This way the policy created in the UI is overwritten, and the UI gets disabled.